# Crear pop-up bootstrap modal por cada estado con botones

Tags: javascript, php, modal

Tengo una tabla donde hay una columna llamada "`estado`", cada usuario/fila/id tiene de serie un estado, véase (`0,1,2`). La descripción de los estados es: 0-inactivo 1-activo 2-baneado. Al cargar la página me salen los estados actuales gracias a una `conexión vía mysql a la bbdd.`

Lo que quiero es: que al clickear sobre una imagen/enlace del usuario X de la columna estado, me pregunte si quiere cambiarlo a los otros dos estados restantes, elegir cual, y activarlo.

Por ejemplo: de serie el usuario/ID 38 tiene de estado=1(activo), quiero clickear sobre su imagen(a href) y me pregunte con dos botones si quiero cambiar al estado (boton0) o al estado (boton2). Y me actualice el resultado.

Código:
Creo que el fallo está aquí:

```
echo "<td onclick='cambiar_estado(this);' width=\"10%\" id=\"".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">" ?>
<!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario. -->
<center>
<?php
    echo "<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_cambiar_estado' data-id='\"".$row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']."\">' class='cambiar_estado' onclick='cambiar_estado(this);'>";
    echo "<img src=\"/imagenes/".$row['estado'].".gif\">";
    echo "</a>"; ?>
</center>
<?php 
    echo "</td>"; 
?>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Cambio de estados - Ventana emergente.</h4>
            </div>    
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>¿Deseas cambiar el estado del usuario/ID?</p>
            </div>    
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="boton_uno" class="boton-estado btn-primary">Boton 1</button>
                <button type="button" id="boton_dos" class="boton-estado btn-primary">Boton 2</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: donde esta el codigo del modal?

Comment: Lo acabo de editar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar esto, debes identificar que estado tiene tu `row`.

Hay 3 escenarios :

- Si tiene estado 0 (inactivo) puede cambiar a : Activo (1) o Baneado (2)
- Si tiene estado 1 (activo) puede cambiar a : Inactivo (0) o Baneado (2)
- Si tiene estado 2 (baneado) puede cambiar a : Inactivo (0) o Activo (1)

No conozco tu codigo completo pero lo que yo haria seria lo siguiente:

En primera instancia debes crear solo UN Modal, en tu codigo creas un footer por cada `row` que vas recorriendo algo asi :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="boton_uno" class="btn_estado btn-primary">Boton 1</button>
            <button type="button" id="boton_dos" class="btn_estado btn-primary">Boton 2</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Este modal tiene 3 botones el primero para cerrar y los otros dos los que tu pides para cambiar el estado. ***Importante*** agregue `id` para identificalos y agregue la clase `btn-estado` ahora explico el porque.

Cuando haces click en `row` llamas a la funcion `cambiar_estado` dentro de esta funcion debes rescatar el estado actual de tu fila y verificar que opciones entregar, algo asi :

```
<script>
    function cambiar_estado(row) {
        var estado = $(row).data('estado');
        var opcion_estado_1;
        var opcion_estado_2;
        var label_estado_1;
        var label_estado_2;
        if(estado == 1){
            opcion_estado_1 = 0;
            label_estado_1 = "Inactivo";
            opcion_estado_2 = 2;
            label_estado_2 = "Baneado";
        }else if(estado == 2){
            opcion_estado_1 = 0;
            label_estado_1 = "Inactivo";
            opcion_estado_2 = 1;
            label_estado_2 = "Activo";
        }else if(estado == 0){
            opcion_estado_1 = 1;
            label_estado_1 = "Activo";
            opcion_estado_2 = 2;
            label_estado_2 = "Baneado";
        }
        $('#boton_uno').attr('estado', opcion_estado_1);
        $('#boton_dos').attr('estado', opcion_estado_2);
        $('#boton_uno').html(label_estado_1);
        $('#boton_dos').html(label_estado_2);
        $('#myModal').modal();
    }

$('.btn-estado').click(function(){
    //Rescatas el atributo estado seteado en el click del row
    var estado = $(this).attr('estado');
    console.log(estado);
})
</script>
```

Esta funcion lo que hace es verificar que estado tiene actual, guardar en variables `opcion_estado_1` y `opcion_estado_2` los posibles valores que puede editar el usuario. (Ademas de los labels para cambiar el texto del boton, esto es por si lo necesitas). Luego setea a los botones con id `boton_uno` y `boton_dos` un atributo llamado `estado`. Y ademas los labels que te nombre anteriormente y levanta el modal `$('#myModal').modal();`

El `modal` va a llevar el contenido que tu desees mas estos botones. Luego capturo el evento `click` en cualquier elemento con clase `btn-estado`, de ese boton OBTENGO el valor `estado` del atributo y ahi recien tu deberias editar el estado de tu objeto, haciendo el llamado a un `ajax` o como lo estes haciendo.

```
$('.btn-estado').click(function(){
    //Rescatas el atributo estado seteado en el click del row
    var estado = $(this).attr('estado');
})
```

**EDICION**

Para que funcione correctamente debes primero en tu `<td>` defines un atributo llamado `estado`

```
 <td onclick="cambiar_estado(this);" id="<?php echo $row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']?>" data-estado="<?php echo $row['estado']?>">
```

Luego en la funcion `cambiar_estado`

Aqui obtienes el valor de `data-estado`, haces lo que te explique anteriormente y todo va a funcionar a la perfeccion. Una vez que hagas click en uno de los botones obtienes el nuevo estado.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48663/discussion-on-answer-by-sioesi-crear-pop-up-bootstrap-modal-por-cada-estado-con).

Comment: gracias @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Cuando puedas @sioesi al chat que tengo una pequeña duda.